# Webcam works with webrtc but not in vlc

Tags: google-chrome, video, vlc, webcam

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Here is the dmesg when I connect the camera. It doesn't look right.

```
[ 4721.516013] input: UVC Camera (046d:0825) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-11/1-11.1/1-11.1.4/1-11.1.4:1.0/input/input21
[ 4722.857466] usb 1-11.1.4: set resolution quirk: cval->res = 384
[ 4780.532548] usb 1-11.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 11
[ 4788.179290] usb 1-11.1.4: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[ 4788.319128] usb 1-11.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=3822
[ 4788.319134] usb 1-11.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 4788.319138] usb 1-11.1.4: Product: USB 2.0 HD Camera 
[ 4788.323968] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 HD Camera  (058f:3822)
[ 4788.327948] uvcvideo 1-11.1.4:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[ 4788.327954] uvcvideo 1-11.1.4:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 6 was not initialized!
[ 4788.327958] uvcvideo 1-11.1.4:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[ 4788.328284] input: USB 2.0 HD Camera : USB 2.0 HD  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-11/1-11.1/1-11.1.4/1-11.1.4:1.0/input/input22
```

When I run VLC using /dev/video0 capture device. I get no image.

When I go to a webrtc site such as https://appr.tc in Chrome, the webcam works.

When I try and use the following gstreamer pipeline to try and stream the cam to VLC, no UDP packets are generated. Which I think means gstreamer can't init the camera or something.

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4lsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! rtph264pay config-interval=10 pt=96 ! udpsink host=224.0.0.1 port=5000
```

Does anyone know what might be going wrong here? And why the behaviour of the webcam appears to be different between Chrome and VLC?

**Update:**

I have now found that if I force the camera resolution in VLC to be 640x480, then video will be displayed. However the image appears to be cropped and at the wrong aspect ratio. Here is the log from VLC when I do this. I have found that if I experiment with other resolutions, it still looks the same no matter what.

```
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: processing request item: v4l2://, node: Playlist, skip: 0
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: rebuilding array of current - root Playlist
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: rebuild done - 9 items, index 8
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: starting playback of new item
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: resyncing on v4l2://
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: v4l2:// is at 6
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: creating new input thread
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: Creating an input for 'v4l2://'
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: requesting art for new input thread
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: using default timeshift path
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: `v4l2://' gives access `v4l2' demux `any' path `'
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: creating demux: access='v4l2' demux='any' location='' file='(null)'
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: looking for access_demux module matching "v4l2": 17 candidates
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: opening device '/dev/video0'
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: Trying Lua scripts in /home/peter/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: no meta fetcher modules matched
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: Trying Lua scripts in /home/peter/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: device USB 2.0 HD Camera : USB 2.0 HD  using driver uvcvideo (version 4.15.18) on usb-0000:00:14.0-11.1.4
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:  with capabilities 0x05200001 (overall 0x85200001)
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: video input Camera 1 (0) is camera
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: selected input 0
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: no video standard selection
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: no tuning required (analog baseband input)
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: no audio input available
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:  supports compressed format MJPG (MJPG): Motion-JPEG
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:  supports raw format YUYV (YUY2): YUYV 4:2:2
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:  emulates raw format RGB3 (RV24): RGB3
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:  emulates raw format BGR3 (RV24): BGR3
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:  emulates raw format YU12 (I420): YU12
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:  emulates raw format YV12 (YV12): YV12
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: selected format YUYV (YUY2)
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:  requested frame internal: 1/60
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:  requested frame size: 640x480
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:   discrete frame interval: 1/30
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: no art finder modules matched
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: Trying Lua scripts in /home/peter/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: no meta fetcher modules matched
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: Trying Lua scripts in /home/peter/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: no art finder modules matched
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: IM: Deleting the input
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: cannot reset cropping limits: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: 614400 bytes maximum for complete image
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: Interlacing setting: progressive
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: color primaries: 8
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: transfer function: 0
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: YCbCr encoding: 0
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: quantization: 0
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: added new video ES YUY2 640x480 (640x480)
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:  frame rate: 30/1
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:  aspect ratio: 1/1
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: selecting program id=0
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: streaming with 4 memory-mapped buffers
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:  integer  Brightness (00980900)
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:   current:   5, default:   5
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:  integer  Contrast (00980901)
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:   current:  15, default:  15
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:  integer  Saturation (00980902)
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:   current:  64, default:  64
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:  integer  Hue (00980903)
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:   current:   0, default:   0
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:  integer  Gamma (00980910)
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:   current: 120, default: 120
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:  menu     Power Line Frequency (00980918)
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:   current: 1, default: 1
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:   choice 0) Disabled
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:   choice 1) 50 Hz
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:   choice 2) 60 Hz
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:  integer  Sharpness (0098091B)
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:   current:  10, default:  10
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:  integer  Backlight Compensation (0098091C)
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:   current:   0, default:   0
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:  menu     Exposure, Auto (009A0901)
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:   current: 3, default: 3
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:   choice 1) Manual Mode
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:   choice 3) Aperture Priority Mode
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:  integer  Exposure (Absolute) (009A0902)
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:   current: 333, default: 312
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:  boolean  Exposure, Auto Priority (009A0903)
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]:   current:  true, default: false
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: using access_demux module "v4l2"
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: looking for video decoder module matching "any": 16 candidates
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: using video decoder module "rawvideo"
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: looking for meta reader module matching "any": 2 candidates
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: Trying Lua scripts in /home/peter/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/reader
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/reader/filename.luac
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: no meta reader modules matched
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: `v4l2://' successfully opened
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: IM: Setting an input
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: IM: Deleting the input
Jun 21 22:28:05 dawkids vlc[23973]: IM: Setting an input
Jun 21 22:28:06 dawkids vlc[23973]: Buffering 0%
Jun 21 22:28:06 dawkids vlc[23973]: trying to reuse free vout
Jun 21 22:28:06 dawkids vlc[23973]: removing module "freetype"
Jun 21 22:28:06 dawkids vlc[23973]: looking for text renderer module matching "any": 2 candidates
Jun 21 22:28:06 dawkids vlc[23973]: Building font databases.
Jun 21 22:28:06 dawkids vlc[23973]: Took -21504 microseconds
Jun 21 22:28:06 dawkids vlc[23973]: using text renderer module "freetype"
Jun 21 22:28:06 dawkids vlc[23973]: reusing provided vout
Jun 21 22:28:06 dawkids vlc[23973]: Received first picture
Jun 21 22:28:06 dawkids vlc[23973]: Logical video size: 640x480
Jun 21 22:28:06 dawkids vlc[23973]: resized to 640x480
Jun 21 22:28:06 dawkids vlc[23973]: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 640x480
Jun 21 22:28:06 dawkids vlc[23973]: Buffering 18%
Jun 21 22:28:06 dawkids vlc[23973]: Buffering 35%
Jun 21 22:28:06 dawkids vlc[23973]: auto hiding mouse cursor
Jun 21 22:28:06 dawkids vlc[23973]: Buffering 53%
Jun 21 22:28:07 dawkids vlc[23973]: Buffering 70%
Jun 21 22:28:07 dawkids vlc[23973]: Buffering 88%
Jun 21 22:28:07 dawkids vlc[23973]: Stream buffering done (319 ms in 316 ms)
Jun 21 22:28:07 dawkids vlc[23973]: Decoder wait done in 0 ms
```

Comment: please try `vlc v4l2:///dev/video0`

Comment: See update. VLC will play if the resolution is set